# Authentication and authorization with different Keycloak servers

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, access-token, rbac

I have a Keycloak server that provides authorization for the different resources of an API Gateway.

The current workflow is: authenticate user with Keycloak, each user with a role assigned, and retrieve the access token. Then, send an HTTP petition to the API GW including the access token. The API GW then gives the token to Keycloak, and if the access token is that from a user with the role required to access the resource, lets the user access to it.

This works as expected, but now I wish to have two different Keycloak servers, one for authentication and another one for authorization. Imagine you have an OrgA and an OrgB (both need to access the resources of the API GW), they both have different users and I don't want to mix them all in one Keycloak. I want to have an authentication Keycloak server for each organization, that assigns their users the roles used by the authorization Keycloak server, and use them to obtain an access token. Then, send that access token to the authorization Keycloak server, that has no info about users, but can give access via role (RBAC).

I have read the Keycloak documentation and I am a little bit lost right now, does anyone know if this is possible?

I haven't tried anything in particular as I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What product are you using as an API GW?

Comment: I am using Apache APISIX right now, but we should be able to use any other API GW, the key is the connection between the different keycloaks